# tail dependence calculation

Tags: r, copula, fat-tails, heavy-tailed

If I have the tail dependence value calculated using Joe (1997) in fact $R$ gives the result for any family copula. Using Caillault and Guegan method called "naive" what are the main differences? Why it will be better to use this method? And more importantly how can I calculate this in $R$?

Many thanks

Comment: Could you please give the link on Caillault and Guegan method?

Comment: @Nick this is the link for the document for Caillault and Guegan method: https://halshs.archives-ouvertes.fr/halshs-00180865/document